# Facebook - embed HTML5 player in feed

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, video, html5-video

I am trying to allow users to embed our custom HTML5 video player in their facebook feed.  I have tried using open graph tags and it just creates an external link to navigate to our site.  I know that it is possible to do this with a flash player, but I need to be able to do this with HTML5.

I see that Vimeo and YouTube have been able to embed their HTML5 players on a users facebook wall when they share a video.  I am trying to do the same and would appreciate advice on this.

Thanks

Comment: As has been said numerous times before, here and elsewhere: That is currently not possible; embedding HTML5 content via iframe is right now only available to a limited set of Facebook partners.

Comment: I've recently seen more of these custom players.  If anyone has any pointers to where or who to contact about the company I work for becoming a partner, I'd be most grateful.